# Need to pass variable value to the json body in a post request in groovy - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, http-post, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to call a POST api in the Jenkins groovy post-build section. I want to pass a groovy variable in the json body of the request.

def url = "someURL"
def body = '[{"PageName" :"worked2","pageurl" :"**url variable value needs to be passed here**"}]'
def http = new URL("some https url").openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("POST")
http.setDoOutput(true)
http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
http.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
http.connect()
def postRC = http.getResponseCode();

I have tried below but nothing worked for me:
'[{"PageName" :"worked2","pageurl" :$url}]'
'[{"PageName" :"worked2","pageurl" :"$url"}]'
'[{"PageName" :"worked2","pageurl" :url}]'

It only works fine when I hard-code the value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked when I used below : 
{"pageurl" :"'+ url +'"}
(double quotes single quotes + variableName + single quotes double quotes)